# DialogFlow Export Description

Tags: export, dialogflow-es

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/export

What does the reference mean by "returned inline" when describing what is done when a uri is not specified?

Answer (score 0):

It means the exported agent will be returned as a response to the request.  e.g. if you call the projects.agent.export RPC method and don't specify `agentUri` the exported agent will be returned as a response to that method/RPC call.